# I am facing this exception org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: while using appium on android device

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, selendroid

org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException - this exception occurs when I try to debug my code, in between (may be because of delay) the app goes at the background and I start getting this exception. I am not sure if it is because of timeout and if yes, where to increase it in appium, as a capability to driver or at server level? I am putting the while trace here, any help will be appreciated.

```
2015-12-16 14:30:15,598 ERROR projects.sdk.lib.ObjectsHandler getElement - 
Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'VDO105-2.local', ip: '192.168.2.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.2', java.version: '1.7.0_75'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id='android:id/home']}
Session ID: 4787f33a-c66e-46af-842b-3a41836b5d2c
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, app=/Users/user/Downloads/app-debug.apk, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=Android, networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={newCommandTimeout=30, app=/Users/user/Downloads/app-debug.apk, deviceName=Android, platformName=Android, serial=4d0025b440ca90d5}, locationContextEnabled=false, newCommandTimeout=30, platformVersion=5.0, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=4d0025b440ca90d5, platformName=Android, webStorageEnabled=false, serial=4d0025b440ca90d5, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]

org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: 
Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'VDO105-2.local', ip: '192.168.2.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.2', java.version: '1.7.0_75'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id='android:id/home']}
Session ID: 4787f33a-c66e-46af-842b-3a41836b5d2c
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, app=/Users/user/Downloads/app-debug.apk, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=Android, networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={newCommandTimeout=30, app=/Users/user/Downloads/app-debug.apk, deviceName=Android, platformName=Android, serial=4d0025b440ca90d5}, locationContextEnabled=false, newCommandTimeout=30, platformVersion=5.0, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=4d0025b440ca90d5, platformName=Android, webStorageEnabled=false, serial=4d0025b440ca90d5, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:345)
    at projects.sdk.lib.ObjectsHandler.getElement(ObjectsHandler.java:84)
    at projects.sdk.lib.ObjectsHandler.menuNavigation(ObjectsHandler.java:142)
    at projects.sdk.lib.Actions.performAction(Actions.java:73)
    at projects.sdk.lib.GetResults.getDeviceJsonResult(GetResults.java:170)
    at projects.sdk.lib.GetResults.getResults(GetResults.java:76)
    at projects.sdk.SDKAdServingTest.sdkTest(SDKAdServingTest.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
2015-12-16 14:30:20,262 ERROR projects.sdk.lib.ObjectsHandler getElement - 
Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'VDO105-2.local', ip: '192.168.2.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.2', java.version: '1.7.0_75'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//android.widget.TextView[@text='Banner']}
Session ID: 4787f33a-c66e-46af-842b-3a41836b5d2c
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, app=/Users/user/Downloads/app-debug.apk, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=Android, networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={newCommandTimeout=30, app=/Users/user/Downloads/app-debug.apk, deviceName=Android, platformName=Android, serial=4d0025b440ca90d5}, locationContextEnabled=false, newCommandTimeout=30, platformVersion=5.0, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=4d0025b440ca90d5, platformName=Android, webStorageEnabled=false, serial=4d0025b440ca90d5, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

Comment: Can you please share code which you have written to connect with device?

Comment: @HelpingHands: I am starting appium as a backend server, not the UI. I am starting server using executing command:  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; /usr/local/bin/appium -g /tmp/applog_12162015_022917.txt --no-reset --command-timeout 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hit and try, I found this solution working: I added this capability to driver:
 capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", timeout);

Answer (score 0):

If appium does not receive any new command for 60 seconds it shuts down automatically.This might be the case when you are debugging your code.
You can verify if appium was shut down automatically by searching the below line in the appium logs:

```
info: [debug] We shut down because no new commands came in
```

Comment: How do I stop appium to die, I am already using argument --command-timeout 60 while starting appium, but this doesn't seem to help, is there any other way out?

Comment: A little late to the party, but try:
DesiredCapabilities capa = new DesiredCapabilities();
capa.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 1000);
...